# Why can't I connect to my network via wired DHCP connection?

Tags: networking, connection, ethernet, dhcp, lan

I am trying to connect to the LAN of the university where I work, on a wired connection.  The Internet is accessed by VPN after connecting to the network.

On Windows 7, the computer seems to automatically connect to the network via DHCP after I plug in an ethernet cable, and lists the relevant VPN so I can enter my username and password.

On Ubuntu 12.10, the VPN is not yet even an issue since NetworkManager cannot even finish the DHCP transaction to connect to the LAN first.

`sudo lspci -v`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20ee
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at fc600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fc625000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

`ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:98:6e:8a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:25ff:fe98:6e8a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:484 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10368 (10.3 KB)  TX bytes:128521 (128.5 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fc600000-fc620000
```

Relevant syslog information:

```
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Auto-activating connection 'Auto Ethernet'.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Auto Ethernet'
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  dhclient started with pid 3062
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: 
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/00:1c:25:98:6e:8a
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:1c:25:98:6e:8a
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Nov 29 22:06:37 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Nov 29 22:06:38 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21c:25ff:fe98:6e8a.
Nov 29 22:06:38 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 29 22:06:38 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: Registering new address record for fe80::21c:25ff:fe98:6e8a on eth0.*.
Nov 29 22:06:40 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Nov 29 22:06:43 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Nov 29 22:06:51 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Nov 29 22:06:57 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Nov 29 22:06:57 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Nov 29 22:06:57 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Nov 29 22:06:57 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Nov 29 22:07:03 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Nov 29 22:07:15 a-ThinkPad-T400 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Nov 29 22:07:22 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3062
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) failed for connection 'Auto Ethernet'
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 NetworkManager[812]:  (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::21c:25ff:fe98:6e8a on eth0.
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21c:25ff:fe98:6e8a.
Nov 29 22:07:23 a-ThinkPad-T400 avahi-daemon[542]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

Comment: It looks like you do not get an DHCP address. Is it possible you contact the network administrator? Maybe there is a reason they do not assign you a DHCP lease.

Comment: @Alex I can contact them again, but is it really possible that this OS is excluded?  It works fine with Windows, and the network people indicate that it also works with Linux. True, I don't have Windows on this machine. But I booted 12.10 from USB on someone else's machine that definitely can connect to the network with Windows, only to replicate this exact problem.